# Compiling link error with xcode 4.2 for my iphone apps

Tags: objective-c, ios

I pass to xcode 4.2 and when I compile I have this error:

```
ld: library not found for -lz.1.2.3
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang
failed with exit code 1.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming lz is supposed to be libz. If that is the case, you are looking for a very specific version of the lib, so you're problem can be fixed by changing it to 1.2. This is done where you add frameworks (Coredata etc) in Xcode.

Hope this helps.